# Removing loops to make my VBA macro able to run on more data

Tags: vba, excel

in my data there are more than a thousand different six digit numbers that are reoccurring in no specific pattern. I need to find all six digit codes that exist in column A and for each number. For example 123456, then find summarize the value in column B for every row that has 123456 in column A. My code is not very effective but the runtime is not a problem if I run with only 10 rows. However, in the real data sheet there are 80 000 rows and my code will take to much time. Can someone help me edit my code but removing certain loops within loops or some stop conditions. I'm  new to VBA and can't do it myself in the limited time I have.

```
Sub Test2()
  Dim summa As Long
  Dim x As Long
  Dim condition As Boolean
  Dim lRows As Long
  Dim k1 As Integer
  Dim i As Long

  x = 1
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

  For i = 100000 To 999999
    k1 = 1
    lRows = 10
    condition = False

    While k1 <= lRows
      If Cells(k1, "A").Value = i Then
        condition = True
      End If    
      k1 = k1 + 1
    Wend

    If condition = True Then
      Cells(x, "F").Value = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), CStr(i), Range("B:B"))
      Cells(x, "E").Value = i
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Next i

  MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: "*I'm new to VBA and can't do it myself in the limited time I have.*" So our time is limited too. No one is going to do all the work for you just because you got a deadline. We don't know what your code does (you didn't tell) and what it should do. You should at least point out were **exactly** your issue is. Also please read [ask].

Comment: Basically column E needs to have all unique values in column A and column F needs to have the sum of column B, as specified in this SumIF. Is there any reason you can't just copy-paste column A into E, use the "Remove Duplicates" from the Ribbon and manually input the SumIF function in column F? / Why do you need VBA?

Comment: Use a pivot table?

Comment: Can't you use Pivot Table? Looks like a work for Pivot Table to me.

Comment: If the code works shouldn't this be moved to CodeReview?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this task. Follow these steps.

1. Insert a blank column C in a copy of the original data sheet.
2. Insert a SUMIF formula, like `=SUMIF(A:A, A2, B:B)` in C2 and copy all the way down.
3. Now all items 123456 will have the same total in column C
4. Copy column C and Paste Values (to replace the formulas with their values).
5. Delete column B.
6. Remove duplicates.